# YII2, валидация даты при обновлении данных

Tags: php, yii2, дата, валидация, update

В модели, имеется правило валидации даты.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        [['date_begin', 'date_end'], 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'],
        [['date_end', 'date_begin'], 'validateDate'],

    ];
}
```

Само правило валидации **"validateDate**"

```
    public function validateDate(){

    $currentDate = Yii::$app->getFormatter()->asDate(time());

    if ($this->date_begin > $this->date_end){
        $this->addError('date_begin', '"Проверьте дату окончания"');
        $this->addError('date_end', '"Дата окончания", не может быть раньше "даты начала');
    }

    if ($currentDate > $this->date_begin) {
        $this->addError('date_begin', '"Дата начала", не может быть раньше текущей даты');
    }

    if ($currentDate > $this->date_end){
        $this->addError('date_end', '"Дата окончания", не может быть раньше текущей даты');
    }

}
```

При создании **"новой записи"** в БД, валидация отрабатывает как положенно.
Однако мне необходимо чтобы при **"обновлении"** уже имеющихся данных, в**алидация не происходила** вновь.

Так как, по истечению нескольких дней, если пользователю потребуется отредактировать какие-либо параметры, скрипт потребует вновь изменить обе даты, чтобы они небыли раньше текущего дня.

**Вопрос повторно.** Что необходимо сделать, чтобы при обновлении данных, валидация не заставляла пользователя вновь изменять даты.

*P.S. Передавать параметр "false",
`$model->update(false);`
или 
`$model->save(false);`
не подходит, так как это пропускает вообще всю валидацию.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как вариант сделать проверку в методе validateDate() на то, новая это запись или нет:

```
if ($this->isNewRecord) {
...
}
```

Но правильней скорее всего будет использовать сценарии: https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-input-validation.html#declaring-rules

Comment: if ($this->isNewRecord) - как вариант учту. Но хотелось бы это реализовать на основе сценария. У вас имеется ли наглядный пример. Так как на просторах интернета, уже более 6 статей просмотрел, но не смог найти подходящего примера.

Comment: Смотрите в официальной документации (https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-models/) - после объявления сценариев нужно в валидацияи добавить параметр 'on'

Answer (score 0):

В результате получилось следующее.

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [

        [['date_begin', 'date_end'], 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'],
        [['date_end', 'date_begin'], 'validateDate'],

    ];
}
```

И непосредственно функция валидации.

```
    public function validateDate(){

    $currentDate = Yii::$app->getFormatter()->asDate(time());

    if ($this->date_begin > $this->date_end){
        $this->addError('date_begin', '"Проверьте дату окончания"');
        $this->addError('date_end', '"Дата окончания", не может быть раньше "даты начала');
    }

    if ($this->isNewRecord){
        if ($currentDate > $this->date_begin) {
            $this->addError('date_begin', '"Дата начала", не может быть раньше текущей даты');
        }

        if ($currentDate > $this->date_end){
            $this->addError('date_end', '"Дата окончания", не может быть раньше текущей даты');
        }
    }

}
```

Как было рекомендовано **OlyLad**, в код просто было добавлено условие. `if ($this->isNewRecord){}`
В принципе это является решением проблемы, код рабочий.
Но, не нашел способ решения проблемы в качестве сценария.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        [['date_begin', 'date_end'], 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'on' => ['create', 'update']],
        [['date_end', 'date_begin'], 'validateDate', 'on' => 'create'],

    ];
}
```

Ну а дальше только в метод scenarios прописать указанные сценарии и в соответствующих местах перед валидацией прописать нужные сценарии:

`$model->scenario = 'update;`